# How to redirect based on views results?

Tags: 7, views, redirection

I have a view that shows a list of nodes and has a contextual filter. 
If the number of nodes shown is only 1 then I want to redirect to that node page instead of showing the view. 
Can I do that in views or do I have to code it?

Comment: **See also:** http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74060

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think Views does anything like that by default, but a quick...

```
if (count($view->result)==1) {
  drupal_goto('node/' . $view->result[0]->nid);
}
```

...at the beginning of a display output template for the view in question should do it for you.

Or better yet, per @MPD...

```
function MOTOMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  if ($view->name=='JUSTONEPLEASE' && count($view->result)==1) {
    drupal_goto('node/' . $view->result[0]->nid);
  } 

  // any other pre_render()ing here

}
```

Comment: great idea. I wonder if I could use a views_php field for that as well.

Comment: Dunno :) Check it out and let us know.  I tend to think if it works it to be a matter of personal preference;  I like to use templates so I can quickly look at them without going into UIs and such and thus I shy away from php fields that are in the DB.

Comment: Do it from a view hook.  Try [hook_views_pre_render](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7)

Comment: D'oh!  I keep on forgetting about that bad boy.  Definitely the right call.