# Can I redirect the user to some other page if the result of a view is empty?

Tags: 7, views, redirection

How do I redirect the user to some other page, when the view returns empty result?

Comment: **See also:** http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37655/how-to-redirect-based-on-views-results

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your views **No results behavior** Choose ' Global: Text area ' choose php filter and add the following code.

```
<?php
 drupal_goto('node/1'); //path to redirect
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I did a few minutes ago :)

Comment: This has security implications, it requires enabling PHP code through PHP filter, which is generally discouraged. https://github.com/dreftymac/public.lab/blob/master/topic/d7/php-filter-implications.md dmid://pageredir_methodic_guard

Answer (score 3):

Better yet do it in your views-view.tpl.php and avoid using PHP in UI like.

```
  <?php if ($rows): ?>
    <div class="view-content">
      <?php print $rows; ?>
    </div>
  <?php elseif ($empty): ?>
    <div class="view-empty">
      <?php drupal_goto('some_page'); ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

if you want to pass query to new url use this for goto

```
drupal_goto('your_url', array('query'=>array(
'variable_name1'=>'variable_value1',
'variable_name2'=>'variable_value2',
'variable_name3'=>'variable_value3',
...... ...
)));
```

or if you want to goto an anchor on page use this

```
drupal_goto("node", array('fragment' => $node->nid));
```